# Twilio Client Conference Call Monitor incomplete output with PHP error

Tags: php, twilio

Trying to implement the Twilio Client Conference Call Monitor as described here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-conference-call-monitor

It "sees" ongoing conferences and has output like this:

```
Found 0 conference(s)
Found 1 conference(s)
etc.
```

However, it doesn't list the ongoing conferences as desired.  No further output is given.

In the ssl_error_log, I found this, which is interesting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Objects
>   returned by Services_Twilio_Page::getIterator() must be traversable or
>   implement interface Iterator' in /mypath/call_monitor.php:74\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /mypath/call_monitor.php(74): unknown()\n#1 {main}\n 
>   thrown in /mypath/call_monitor.php on line 74

I don't find any results here or on Google for this message, so I'm thinking it's particular to my setup.

I'm using Linux / Apache / PHP Version 5.2.17.

Answer (score 0):

The support team at Twilio advised the following:

> ...it looks like there's a bug in the example code. Can you change
>   this:

```
$conferences = $client->account->conferences->getPage(0, 50, array('Status' => 'in-progress'));
```

to:

```
$conferences = $client->account->conferences->getIterator(0, 50, array('Status' => 'in-progress'));
```

> i.e. change "getPage" to "getIterator" ?

This corrected the error I reported, but introduced other issues not within the scope of this question.